# Google cloud platform http post

Tags: http, google-cloud-platform, http-post

I need to use google cloud database but the data must be post from external device using http post request. Someone has a tutorial or example to do that?
Thanks

Comment: Please give more details. The "Device" add data to the database or query the database? what you are building?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have a weintek hmi that update every X minutes a row in the database so actually I have a hosted mysql and from the hmi I post data to a php file on the website that make the update query in the database. After, I have an ios app that make some request always in http to the php that return a json of the query done from ios. Now I need to implement push notifications to ios but the hosted website don’t give me to go outside so I’m thinking to move to a cloud like google cloud but I don’t now if and how it’s possible to do

Comment: I suggest you try firebase for messaging from gcloud.https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Comment: There is another firebase document that you can check as well and help you to achieve your goals https://firebase.google.com/docs/database